# Is OpenSSL thread safe?

Tags: c, openssl, centos

Should there be an issue if I do SSL handshake in one thread and SSL_read and SSL_write in a separate thread?

Comment: Can you post some code samples?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**

[OpenSSL threads manual](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/threads.html)

> OpenSSL can safely be used in multi-threaded applications provided
>   that at least two callback functions are set, locking_function and
>   threadid_func.

[Recommended library setup sample](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/demos/threads/mttest.c)

```
void thread_setup(void)
{
    int i;

    lock_cs = OPENSSL_malloc(CRYPTO_num_locks() * sizeof(HANDLE));
    for (i = 0; i < CRYPTO_num_locks(); i++) {
        lock_cs[i] = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
    }

    CRYPTO_set_locking_callback((void (*)(int, int, char *, int))
                                win32_locking_callback);
    /* id callback defined */
}

void thread_cleanup(void)
{
    int i;

    CRYPTO_set_locking_callback(NULL);
    for (i = 0; i < CRYPTO_num_locks(); i++)
        CloseHandle(lock_cs[i]);
    OPENSSL_free(lock_cs);
}
```